# Laravel: advice for showing big, unchanging outline

Tags: laravel

My laravel app is a big family tree website. I have Person records (id, first, last, DOB, parent_family_id, etc) and Family records (id, caption, mother_id, father_id, original_bool).

Everything's done now except for my last challenge: an outline view! I have a number of 'original families' (the earliest ones), and for each of them I'd like to be able to display their descendants all the way down to present day in an outline form (kids, those kids' families, those families' kids, etc).

So far I've written a few functions in the relevant controller:

- get_kids_of_family($family)
- get_families_person_made($person)
- get_descendants($family, $results)- this will be a recursive function that calls get_kids_of_family, adds them to a results set (some gigantic array that I'll pass along?), then for each of them it calls get_families_person_made, adds them to the results set, calls get_descendants on each of those families, etc.

**Then it occurred to me: even if I can get this working, it'll be crunching around through a lot of data, and it rarely changes (weekly/monthly at most, with the discovery of a new person).** Therefore I'm wondering if it makes sense to make/run a script to save the results someplace (like an xml or json file) and then somehow pass that file to my view for display.

Thoughts? What's a good (but not too advanced) way to implement something like this in a laravel app?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/cache

Comment: yup this is doing it- thanks!